# Argocd: Matrix generator for dynamically generated elements

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have a git generator config yaml file that looks like this

```
configs:  
  cluster-url : https://kubernetes.default.svc
  oe-namespaces:  
    - oe-ns-1
    - oe-ns-2
    - oe-ns-3
```

I would like to install the application to multiple namespaces. For that i can use this
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-List/#dynamically-generated-elements

But how do I combine the `configs.cluster-url` into the iteration

As of now, this supports only iteration from the   `oe-namespaces` array

`elementsYaml: "{{ .key.components | toJson }}"`

Is it possible to combine the `cluster-url` without adding to the `oe-namespaces` array?